# Using a SuperDrive temporarily for one time installations?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

Does Apple (or any oter company) have such a service which would let you temporarily use a SuperDrive (or other external DVD Drive)? I have a MacBook Air and in order to install boot camp, I need an external DVD drive. Paying $80 for a one-time use of a DVD drive sounds absurd. For that reason, I was wondering if Apple or any other company has some kind of service which allows you to bring in your laptop and use a SuperDrive for one time installations. I wouldn't even mind paying for such a service as long as it's significantly lower than the $80 for a SuperDrive.

Any other ideas besides buying a cheaper alternative of the SuperDrive?

Comment: Is there a place anywhere near you that rents computers? See if they'll rent you a MacBook Air with an optical drive—and then tell them you don't need the MacBook Air.

Comment: @Dori: good idea... now I have to find such a place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a ONE TIME install, go to any Apple Store and let them use one of the drives there. I'm sure they'll have no problem. Tell them you want to try before you buy ;)

In other news, you can put Windows 7 on a USB Stick and install it from there. I've used the DVD only once, to create the USB Stick. There are instructions over the net on how to do that, even from outside Windows (but if you have a Win machine to do it, it's faster because there's a free tool).

Comment: I just called Apple and it seems like this might work. They recommended I make a Genius bar appointment for it. By the way, do you happen to have the link to the instructions you used to create the USB stick you mention?

Comment: @Senseful yes, I remember using Google and picking up this ARSTechnica article: http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm trying to install Windows by using the USB flash drive, but I ran into some problems: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8044 -- Could you please take a look at it to see if it's something you know how to resolve? Thanks!

Comment: @Senseful I'll be out for a few days, but I'll see if I can take a look at some point.

Comment: No problem. It's not that important anymore, because I tried your suggestion about going to the Apple store, and it worked. However, it would be nice to resolve that issue for the future/other people.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CD drive of any other computer (Mac or Windows) on your network, for free. See [this Apple doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1777) for directions.

Comment: Yup good answer.  I was trying to find that article.  I was thinking it was 'target disk mode' but you found the right one.

Comment: This is the one that Apple recommends. IIRC, Jobs mentioned it at the keynote when they released the Air.

Comment: That doesn't work for a boot camp installation, see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2298

Comment: @Senseful What... that sucks. Why, Apple?

Comment: Not why Apple, but why Microsoft.  The Windows installer doesn't know how to work over a network.  It's difficult to even get it to work off a thumb drive.

Comment: At Windows installation time you only have the hardware available that the Windows installation media supports, and networking isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  If I were you, I'd find a way to image the DVD and deploy it onto a USB stick.  You never know when you might need it.  I *think* it's as simple as imaging it, and then in Disk Utility, "restoring" the image to the USB device of your choice.

But I've never done that, so I don't know.

Comment: I was able to image the DVD onto a USB stick using [this method](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars). The [problem is installing it](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8044).