# How do I uninstall rEFIt?

Tags: startup, macos

I installed [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) in order to [install boot camp via a USB key](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8044/how-can-i-install-boot-camp-off-a-windows-7-usb-flash-drive). Now that Boot Camp is installed, I no longer need rEFIt, so I'm trying to uninstall it.

I followed the [uninstall directions](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s3_remove.html) for "Removal when using rEFItBlesser", because when I installed it, I ran "rEFIt.mpkg" (i.e. the installer package). I trashed the "efi" folder, and "rEFItBlesser". I restarted the computer twice, and the menu still appears when the computer starts up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the solution is the same one listed there under "troubleshooting". Initially I was thrown off by the wording used. I thought that "If Mac OS X no longer starts up.." meant OS X didn't start up at all, but what it really means is "If Mac OS X does not start up automatically instead of rEFIt..."

I just followed the directions listed there and now it uses the default boot sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video link that I hope you find helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxq8nLX-Uzw