# Enabling external booting on a fusion drive Mac

Tags: mac, recovery, fusion-drive

I am trying to change the secure boot settings so that I can allow booting from an external disk. Normally to do this you would go into recovery mode with command + r and then change the settings. When I try to do this, however, my mac decides to boot up using recovery mode with internet, in which I cannot change the secure boot settings from. After doing a little research, this seems to be because my Mac has a fusion drive, which is causing the regular recovery mode to not start up. My question is: how do I get into regular recovery mode on a fusion drive Mac? If I can’t, how do I change the secure boot settings without going into recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1)

Wait for Internet recovery to finish loading, proceed with normal steps.

P.S. this shouldn't be necessary unless you've enabled the option to disallow booting from external media. If that is the case, see this article for instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198#open

Option 2)

If you're impatient like me, go to `System Preferences > Startup Disk`.

Click on the drive you wish to boot from, click `Restart`.

Comment: Option 1) that’s the thing though, you can’t change the boot settings in internet recovery

Comment: Option 2) The external disk that I want to boot from is greyed out, presumably  because the external booting settings is off

Comment: Edit: I was able to restart from the startup disk section in settings, but all that did was take me to the startup manager, where my external disk is not showing

Comment: If it's greyed out, it's probably not recognizing it as a valid startup disk. Could you share a little more info about the external hdd? How is it formatted? Does it have a valid OS installed? Is it different than the one you currently have installed? For example, I have an old iMac running Sierra. I tried booting from an external HDD that had Mojave installed, but it was greyed out. Turns out, I had to install High Sierra, then Mojave, on the iMac first before it would boot Mojave on the external due to otherwise missing firmware updates.

Comment: P.S. I don't know why Option 3) slipped my mind -- power on mac, immediately press and hold option key until disks options are displayed. P.P.S. I just recalled another issue on my wife's iMac about a year ago. She had an external SSD as well, and it became corrupt. I plugged it into another mac and ran repair from Disk Utility which was able to fix some issues and it was then bootable again.

Comment: It’s a 750gb that I installed windows on using wintousb

Comment: Do you have any other computers you could boot that disk from? I'm going to take a wild guess and say it's not bootable. By any chance, do you recall whether you chose MBR for BIOS or GPT for UEFI option?

Comment: Found this. Might be helpful to you. Seems to offer some solutions specific to wintousb: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57125/how-do-i-boot-from-a-windows-usb-with-a-mac

Comment: Can you add to your question the results of the terminal command : `diskutil list internal `

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherent about a Fusion drive that means you won't have a Recovery Partition.

First thing to do is create a recovery partition on the Fusion drive.  Download "Recovery Partition Creator" from here:
https://musings.silvertooth.us/downloads-2/

You'll need an installer app for the OS.